Missing option to request an edit to provide more details in late answer review
I have put this is for a feature request. Here is the new specification.
I was reviewing a late answer, and I wanted to request that the OP revise their post with more details. However, I don't see that option:

Here is my logic on why the other choices don't work for me:

Looks Ok: The post has very little detail or effort put in. It is not ok.
Edit: This also is not an option because I am not necessarily familiar with every topic for every answer I review.
Recommended deletion: This is completely inappropriate since the post can be improved.

I could choose another action, but that doesn't seem like the ideal course of action.
Why has the "suggest improvement" option been removed?

You might be used to the First Answer queue, which does have a Share Feedback button. But you can still skip or leave a comment!

The "correct" solution is to leave a comment and then select "Other action".
That said, this is somewhat unsatisfying, as I think people commonly tend to select "Recommend deletion" when they shouldn't due to thinking those are the only available options.  The Low Quality Answers queue is even worse for this, because it doesn't even have the "Other action" option.
Ideally, the UI should be improved to make it clearer that leaving a comment should be considered as a possible action.

"The "correct" solution is to leave a comment and then select 'Other action'." That is what I did on the last couple of answers. That said this could be misleading especially to those who haven't seen the other options. I think adding, "other action" and "Share feedback" should be considered by the SO team.

@Ethan mind creating a [meta-tag:feature-request] for that? A comment mentioning that it should exist doesn't really bring it to the attention of the company.

@Abdul Aziz Barkat Added for feature request.
